# How to include only matching days?

Tags: r, excel

I have data that looks like this in excel:

```
Date1       Value1  Date2       Value2
1/2/2004    17      1/3/2004    27
1/3/2004    26      1/4/2004    30
1/4/2004    22      1/5/2004    22
1/5/2004    17      1/6/2004    28
1/13/2004   15      1/7/2004    17
1/14/2004   10      1/14/2004   21
```

And i want to exclude any values that its associted date doesn't exist in both series.

for the sample data i posted the result should look like this:

```
Date1       Value1  Date2       Value2
1/3/2004    26      1/3/2004    27
1/4/2004    22      1/4/2004    30
1/5/2004    17      1/5/2004    22
1/14/2004   10      1/14/2004   21
```

Comment: Will there be duplicated dates in either the Date1 or Date2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to `merge` the data. We can first create a list with the first two columns as the first list item, and the second two columns as the second list item, and then use `Reduce` to merge on "Date1" and "Date2", like this:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by.x = "Date1", by.y = "Date2"),
       list(mydf[1:2], mydf[3:4]))
#       Date1 Value1 Value2
# 1 1/14/2004     10     21
# 2  1/3/2004     26     27
# 3  1/4/2004     22     30
# 4  1/5/2004     17     22
```

Also, not sure how foolproof this would be, but you could try:

```
A <- mydf[match(mydf$Date2, mydf$Date1, nomatch = FALSE), 1:2]
B <- mydf[match(mydf$Date1, mydf$Date2, nomatch = FALSE), 3:4]

cbind(A, B)
```

Or even:

```
temp <- rbind(mydf[1:2], setNames(mydf[3:4], names(mydf)[1:2]))
temp <- temp[duplicated(temp$Date1) | duplicated(temp$Date1, fromLast = TRUE), ]
do.call(cbind, split(temp, ave(temp$Date1, temp$Date1, FUN = seq_along)))
```

Comment: Hi, Ananda,
I was wondering if i could apply the first code on more than two series, so i have the same sample but with over 100 different dates and values.
Thanks again.